# How To Perform Multiple Radio Button Click in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, radio-button

How to make condition to perform multiple radio button click (see image below)...?

[multiple radio button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCaiK.jpg)

I've tried for hours, but I got only single radio button click (see attached image)

[single radio button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNOdV.jpg)

```
List<WebElement> radiobutton = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@type='radio']"));
    System.out.println("Total element is " + radiobutton.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < radiobutton.size(); i++) {

        // if you are getting stale element exception because of the page
        // reload
        radiobutton = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@type='radio']"));

        System.out.println(radiobutton.get(i).getAttribute("value"));

        // select your radio and click to go to next page
        radiobutton.get(i).click();

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='btnCheckFare']"))
                .click();

        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
```

Comment: Why do not you show that you have tried already.

Comment: Only one radio button can be selected in a group! Do you mean select one by one? And post the HTML for better responses.

Comment: You can see in this video

multiple radio button using human interaction

https://youtu.be/KxydkdhNdYc?t=143

Answer (score 0):

I saw your video.You have multiple groups of radio button and you can select one radio button in each group.

You have to use 2 loops,one for group and one inner loop for select radio button in a group.

If you have experience in programming then you can do it easily.Otherwise provide the link where we can see this functionality.